# PHP Echo json_encode

Tags: php, json

I am having a small problem, I am showing json using PHP, I have this code:

```
foreach($result as $r){

        $returnEcho["Id"]       = $r["id"];
        $returnEcho["Username"] = $r["username"];
        $returnEcho["Email"]    = $r["email"];
        $returnEcho["Info"]     = $r["Info"];

        echo json_encode($returnEcho);
```

The problem with this code is, it will display the JSON like this:

```
{"Username":"X","Email":"X","Info":"X"}
{"Username":"X","Email":"X","Info":"X"}
{"Username":"X","Email":"X","Info":"X"}
```

But what I want is something like this:

```
[   
 {
  "Username":"X",
  "Email":"X",
  "Info":"X"
 },
 {
  "Username":"X",
  "Email":"X",
  "Info":"X"
 }
]
```

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to build everything in an array and `echo` the json only after `foreach` finish. Like this:

```
 $return = [];
 foreach($result as $r){
    $returnEcho["Id"]       = $r["id"];
    $returnEcho["Username"] = $r["username"];
    $returnEcho["Email"]    = $r["email"];
    $returnEcho["Info"]     = $r["Info"];
    $return[] = $returnEcho;
 }
 echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for.